# Compatibility of acer aspire one 722 with ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, acer

I was wondering if I can install Ubuntu 12.10 on my Acer Aspire One 722 netbook. 
It is currently running Windows 7 Home Premium but I want to use Ubuntu alongside with it.

Spesifications:

- 2 GB RAM
- AMD C-60 APU dual core 1.00GHz
- ATI Radeon 128MB dedicated graphics

Answer (score 2):

I am running 12.10 on Acer Aspire One 722 right now. It mostly works fine. my only current issue is the internal and external microphones are not working. [There is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1074615) report.

The graphics performance in Ubuntu is not as good as in windows.

There is a ton of information relevant for 722 in the 522 page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne522

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne722

The following thread in ubuntuforums is also useful.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811178

---

**Update:** the internal microphone works after the upgrade to **Ubuntu 13.04.** Everything works!

Hope this helps